# How can I remove an item from a repeated protobuf field in python?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf message that contains a repeated field. I would like to remove one of the items in the list but I can't seem to find a good way to do so without copying all of the items out of the repeated field into a list, clearing the repeated field, and repopulating it.

In C++ there is a `RemoveLast()` function, but this doesn't seem to appear in the python API...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As noted in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated), the object wrapping a repeated field in Protobuf behaves like a regular Python sequence. Therefore, you should be able to simply do

```
del foo.fields[index]
```

For example, to remove the last element,

```
del foo.fields[-1]
```

Comment: If you want to delete all of the repeated fields, use `del foo.fields[:]`

Answer (score 2):

In Python, deleting an element from a list could be done in this way:

```
list.remove(item_to_be_removed)
```

or

```
del list[index]
```

Comment: This is not a python list. It's a custom type. Remove is not a member.

Comment: @Catskul this actually works as of protobuf 2.6; they've added the pythonic list-like operations `extend()` and `remove()` to the `RepeatedCompositeFieldContainer` type.

Answer (score -1):

```
const google::protobuf::Descriptor  *descriptor = m_pMessage->GetDescriptor();
const google::protobuf::Reflection  *reflection = m_pMessage->GetReflection();
const google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor* field = descriptor->FindFieldByName("my_list_name");
if (i<list_size-1)
{
    reflection->SwapElements(m_pMessage, field, i, list_size-1);
}
reflection->RemoveLast(m_pMessage, field);
```